# Sum of transformations of continuous uniform random variable

Tags: probability, trigonometry, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$. I want to find the cdf of

$$
\sin^2(X) + \cos^2(X)
$$
My feeling is that since $\sin^2(X) + \cos^2(X) = 1$, the cdf will be:
$$F(1 \le x)=
\begin{cases}
1, \text{if } 1 \le x \\
0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The only thing I am not sure about is whether $\sin^2(X) + \cos^2(X) = 1$, because $X$ is a random variable, not a real number. However, this identity works even if I replace $x$ with a real-valued function $g(x)$, namely
$$\sin^2(g(x)) + \cos^2(g(x)) = 1$$
Random variables are real-valued functions so I don't see why this may fail.

I would very much appreciate if someone with more expertise than me can let me know if I am heading the right direction or if I am completely off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formal argument is: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ a probabilistic space and $A:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ a random variable.

Set $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that Borel measurable. Then $g\circ A:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is random variable.

Now, let $U$ a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $U\subseteq(Im(g))^c$ (that is, $U$ doesn't have elements of $Im(g)$). Then $(g\circ A)^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$.

Thus $P((g\circ A)^{-1}(U))=0$.

Now, for your question:

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Take $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\sin^2 x+\cos^2x(=1)$. Then $g\circ X$ is a random variable in the probabilistic space where $X$ is defined. Moreover, $Im(g)=1$. Suppose $x<1$. The borel set $U=(-\infty,x]$ is contained in $Im(g)^c$

By the observations above, we have, $P((g\circ X)^{-1}(U))=0$. But $P((g\circ U)^{-1}(U))=P(g\circ X\in U)=P(\cos^2X+\sin^2X\le x)$. Thus $0=P(\cos^2X+\sin^2X\le x)$ for all $x<1$.

A similar argument shows that $P(\cos^2X+\sin^2X\le x)=1$ iff $x\ge 1$.

Now you can rest assured that what you've done is right.

Finally, please note that the unique condition on $X$ is $g\circ X$ to be well defined.

Comment: Much obliged. Thanks especially for taking the time to go through the measure-theoretic details of the argument!